# How to add a div to a list of words using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a table in standard HTML. But i have a lot of words to be wrapped in div tags. Normally I would do this server side or something but that isn't a reality in this project. So i'm restricted to plain old web technologies. I was wondering though, if there is a python solution to my problem (i.e. creating a small script so i can run through a list of given words, output the required HTML, and then copy and paste the HTML into various html files). So if i have a list of words below, could i run a python program, and add the needed divs with the classes to each word. One problem would be the "order" needs to increment to the amount of words given.

Words

```
animals
cat
dog
mouse
lion
```

What the output should be

```
 <div class="Rtable Rtable--1cols">
<div style="order:0" class="Rtable-cell-head">animals</div>
    <div style="order:1;" class="Rtable-cell">cat</div>
    <div style="order:2;" class="Rtable-cell">dog</div>
    <div style="order:3;" class="Rtable-cell">mouse</div>
    <div style="order:4;" class="Rtable-cell">lion</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have a look at http://jinja.pocoo.org/ or some other template engine.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use a templating engine. I'm stuck to front end web technologies BUT i thought i could create a small script I could run independently before adding the outputted HTML to required files.

Comment: You need a tool like BeautifulSoup to *parse* HTML, because you must be prepared to various idioms or errors. But it is fine to build HTML *by hand* because it is only trivial character string processing. Something like `print prolog` `for i in wordlist: print(line_template.format(i))` `print(epilog)`.

Comment: i do not understand... if you can use python (and maybe install an additional library) what prevents you from using a (templating) library? what do you mean by 'front end web technologies' in this context?

Comment: I'm not using python on my web site. It's restricted to just HTML, css and js. This is because of the e-commerce platform I'm having to use-they restrict me to just plain HTML, css and js.. I thought a possible solution would be to create a script I could run on my machine, output the required HTML in a file or just on the IDLE shell, and then copy and paste this result into a html file. It's maybe a stupid idea but it's the best I could think of given the limitations

Comment: of course you can do that. but then again: what prevents you from using a templating library?

Comment: Because the site I'm working on isn't my full time occupation, the people i'm working for, for this site, find it difficult to use basic html let alone trying to get them to understand a template library. So therefore having a solution where they can just paste in a bunch of words to a particular easy to find place, to get given something they can copy and paste to a particular place is the best (only solution) solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jinja solution:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template("""
<div class="Rtable Rtable--1cols">
<div style="order:0" class="Rtable-cell-head">animals</div>
    {%- for order, animal in animals %}
        <div style="order:{{ order }};" class="Rtable-cell">{{ animal }}</div>
    {%- endfor %}
</div>
""")

animals = """
cat
dog
mouse
lion
""".split()

print(template.render(animals=list(enumerate(animals, 1))))
```

output:

```
<div class="Rtable Rtable--1cols">
<div style="order:0" class="Rtable-cell-head">animals</div>
        <div style="order:1;" class="Rtable-cell">cat</div>
        <div style="order:2;" class="Rtable-cell">dog</div>
        <div style="order:3;" class="Rtable-cell">mouse</div>
        <div style="order:4;" class="Rtable-cell">lion</div>
</div>
```

Pure python version:

```
from __future__ import print_function

template = """
<div class="Rtable Rtable--1cols">
<div style="order:0" class="Rtable-cell-head">animals</div>\
    {animals}
</div>
"""

animal_template = """
    <div style="order:{order};" class="Rtable-cell">{animal}</div>"""

animals = """
cat
dog
mouse
lion
""".split()

animal_divs = ''.join([animal_template.format(order=i, animal=animal)
                       for i, animal in enumerate(animals, 1)])
print(template.format(animals=animal_divs))
```

the output is the same.

**update:** the great convenience of Python's split is that it removes all white space (including newlines), however, if you have animal names with spaces in them (e.g. `"white rhino"`) then you'll need to take another approach where you split by lines, strip any whitespace from each line, and skip the line if it contains only whitespace:

```
animals = [animal.strip() for animal in """
cat
dog
mouse
lion
""".splitlines() if animal.strip()]
```

(this solution is similar to the node.js solution below)

However, if your users know javascript and not Python, then a node.js solution might be better:

```
const animals = `
  cat
  dog
  mouse
  lion
  `.split('\n').map(v => v.trim()).filter(v => !!v);

const animal_template = (animal, order) => `<div style="order:${order+1};" class="Rtable-cell">${animal}</div>`;

const template = animals => `
<div class="Rtable Rtable--1cols">
<div style="order:0" class="Rtable-cell-head">animals</div>
    ${animals.map(animal_template).join('\n    ')}
</div>`

console.log(template(animals));
```

Comment: Awesome i love nodejs myself but i'll see what they say. One thing noticed with your pure solution, if there are spaces i.e. if let's say i add 'white rhino' to the list of animals, this gets split into 2 different divs.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a Python version of the node.js animal-splitting code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use bs4 to create, manipulate and delete html : `pip install beautifulsoup4`

- read the file containing the list of words (1 element per line)

```
with open('/path/to/list', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

- create the html you need :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# creating parent
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="Rtable Rtable--1cols"></div>')

# adding head
new_tag = soup.new_tag('div', **{'class': 'Rtable Rtable--1cols'}) 
new_tag.string = line[0]
soup.append(new_tag)

# adding elements
for i, line in enumerate(lines[1:]):
    new_tag = soup.new_tag('div', **{'class': 'Rtable-cell', 'style': f'order:{i};'}) 
    new_tag.string = line
    soup.append(new_tag)

print(soup)
```